# IneligibleDataPartition - S2D not starting - error 2

Tags: storage-spaces, cluster-shared-volumes, storage-spaces-direct

Getting this report but can't find any usefull info how to bind these disk back together:

```
Get-Cachediskstatus.ps1
----------------------------------------
Node: NAS13
DiskState               DiskName                                           DeviceNumber CacheDeviceNumber HasSeekPenalty
---------               --------                                           ------------ ----------------- -------------
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHUSJXF                          2            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHUT6GF                          1            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHV2LWF                          4            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHV2L6F                          5            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHV2V4F                          3            = unbound         true
InitializedAndBound     INTEL SSDPEDMX012T7 - CVPF744100JG1P2JGN_00000001. 6            = cache           false
    
Device counts: cache  capacity 5
Attempted to divide by zero.         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
----------------------------------------
Node: NAS15
DiskState               DiskName                                           DeviceNumber CacheDeviceNumber HasSeekPenalty
---------               --------                                           ------------ ----------------- -------------
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900JETKB - 2630A05SFUWB1605                  3            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FBVFQ - KXHU20WF                          5            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900JETKB - 2630A068FUWB1605                  2            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FDJYR - S3L2MQQ30000M6193W90              1            = unbound         true
IneligibleDataPartition HP EG0900FDJYR - S3L2MP0T0000M620DAMA              4            = unbound         true
InitializedAndBound     INTEL SSDPEDMX012T7 - BTPF73740AZX1P2JGN_00000001. 6            = cache           false

Device counts: cache  capacity 5
Attempted to divide by zero:        + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ForEach-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand
```

did try to repair the volume using these flags:

```
 Remove-Clustersharedvolume -name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)"
 Get-ClusterResource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)" | Set-ClusterParameter -Name diskrunchkdsk -Value 7
 Get-ClusterResource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)" | Set-ClusterParameter -Name diskrecoveryaction -Value 1
 Start-clusterresource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)"
 Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Data Integrity Scan for Crash Recovery" | Start-ScheduledTask
 Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Data Integrity Scan for Crash Recovery"
```

and, when "Ready" again:

```
 Stop-clusterresource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)"
 Get-ClusterResource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)" | Set-ClusterParameter -Name diskrecoveryaction -Value 0
 Get-Clusterresource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)" | set-clusterparameter -name diskrunchkdsk -value 0
 Add-clustersharedvolume -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)"
 Start-clusterresource -Name "Cluster Virtual Disk (Volume1)"
```

always getting the same error:

> Event ID: 1793 Error Code: 2 Reason: OpenPartitionFailure
> Event ID: 1069 The error code was '0x2' ('The system cannot find the file specified.').

Any tips?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Delete all the existing partitions from your disks (and better - wipe them off) before you're adding them to the Storage Spaces [Direct] pools.

https://www.diskpart.com/diskpart/delete-partition-4125.html